# Compute the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $L = −\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} $.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

Compute the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of
$L = −\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} $.

$$D(L) = \{ f ∈ C^2([0, 1], C)\mid f'(0) = f'(1) = 0\}$$

and

$$L = \frac{1}{r(x)} \left( -\frac{d}{dx} p(x)\frac{d}{dx} + q(x) \right).$$

I'm trying to do the following. Take $y \in D(L)$, and apply the operator 
$L[y] = −\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} $, then $-y''(x) = \dfrac{1}{r(x)} \left( -\dfrac{d}{dx} p(x)\dfrac{dy}{dx} + q(x) \right)= \dfrac{1}{r(x)} \left( -\dfrac{d}{dx} p(x)y'(x) + q(x) \right)$, therefore

$$-y''(x)r(x) = -(p(x)y'(x))' + q(x) = -p'(x)y'(x)-p(x)y''(x) + q(x).$$

I need to solve the following problem
$$y''(x)[r(x) -p(x)]-p'(x)y'(x) + q(x)=0.$$

Now I can not find the eigenvalues ​​and eigenfunctions from here.
Can someone help me?

Comment: See my edits for proper use of \mid and proper formatting of $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ as in $$ D(L) = \{ f ∈ C^2([0, 1], C)\mid f'(0) = f'(1) = 0\}$$ $$ \{\cdots \cdots\} $$ $$\left\{ \quad \cdots \vphantom{\frac{ \displaystyle\sum}{\displaystyle\sum}} \cdots \quad \right\}$$

Comment: Don't understand here. You start off with the specific operator $L = -d^2/dx^2$ and then you try to find the eigenvalues ​​and eigenfunctions of the general operator $L = 1/r(x) \cdots$. ?? The specific operator is the general one for $r(x) = p(x) = 1$ and $q(x) = 0$. This is the one you are to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for. Start off with the definining equation $Ly = \lambda y \to -y'' = \lambda y$ and solve the ODE. Apply boundary conditions to find the allowed values of $\lambda$ (the eiegnvalues).

Comment: When you apply $L$ to $y$, there will be a factor of $q$ multiplying $y$, not just $q$ alone.

Comment: The eigenfunctions of $L=-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$
with the von-Neumann conditions $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$ are $f_{n}(x)=\sin{\pi{n}x}$ with $\lambda_{n}=(\pi{n})^{2}$. the igenfunctions of the second operator are not known in the closed form, however you may show that they satisfy some special properties, like orthonormality, etc.

Comment: @KirylPesotski : Just a nit-picky remark: Neumann conditions are associated with Carl Neumann. John von Neumann is a different person.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts never realized that! Thank you very much indeed! Love that forum))

Comment: However this is sort of evident when you think about the time scales of when the pdes were developed!)